# Shall we add one or more custom "Off-Topic Close Reasons"?

Tags: discussion

**9 July update**

3 voters doesn't seem to be enough interest to make the change I was proposing.

**1 July update**

Noone has expressed "don't do this". Speak up soon.

Also, proposed wording has been tweaked, see the proposed answer below.

**Original question**

Shall we add one (or more) custom, "off-topic" close reasons?

[image: Off-topic close reasons we can change]

Comment: Are we about ready to pull the trigger on this?

Comment: I'm thinking a total of three voters (Q has +3/-0, A has +3/-0) is not enough interest from the community to add these particular close reasons.

Answer (score 4):

**Context**

We recently edited the **default** explanation text that is shown when we close/hold a question as "Off-Topic". We will always have the other close reasons (such as "Too Broad"), and we will always have the "migrate to another stack" option.

**Let's add two custom close reasons...**

1. "This question might be better suited on Server Fault. (NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Your question falls outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please see What topics can I ask about here? for more details.)"
2. "This question might be better suited on Super User. (NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Your question falls outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please see What topics can I ask about here? for more details.)"

SE policy is to NOT migrate a question if it does not have any answers. Since we want to be fast at closing things, this means we OFTEN have questions where someone comments "you should ask this on SF/SU" before we close.

So having two new close, off-topic reasons that describe the two most common, "you should ask this on..." cases. Would save us time and comments.

**1 July tweak**

Changed the "should be asked" firm wording, to a softer "might be better suited" since we can't say for sure what the other stacks will take.

Comment: That is a useful idea.

Comment: Yes, great idea.  Is there a way we can somehow briefly list (or link to) the topics for Super User / SF in each of those close reasons?  That way its less of a "this is wrong here, go somewhere else" but more of a "this is wrong here, but its right to ask here"?

Comment: I've voted to close more homework questions than anything else especially questions that put forth zero effort.  I'd like a Custom close that tactfully conveys the message, "No, we won't do your homework for you."

Comment: I'm honestly not so fond of migration targets; one of the bigger problems with closing to another site is that many people have no clue what is or is not on topic there.  [The problem is that someone may ask a lousy question here about server network configuration, we vote to close to [sf], but [sf] people don't like the question because it wasn't documented well (or it involves unmanaged switches which are off-topic there as well)

Comment: Mike brings up a good point. It might be a better idea to word it less authoritative.  Maybe replace _"This question **should** be asked..."_ with _"This question **might** be a better suited for..."_.  I think the intent of this has promise, but I'm also inclined to believe that we aren't as well versed with on-topic/off-topic subjects for SF/SU as we are for NE.

Comment: Good points about not be "authoritative" about things belonging on other stacks. I've adjusted my wording above. Bear in mind that SE warns the custom close reasons should be used judiciously, so this Q is proposing these two close reasons as MAJOR issues we deal with a lot. gnw's comment about homework is also excellent, but my perception is that HW Qs don't rise to the level of things that 'probably should' have been asked on SU or SF.