# Graduated and new design, so let's take some time to polish the site

Tags: discussion, site-content

It's taken a while, but the site has graduated from beta and we have been given a great new design to make the site look great. However as I look around, I still see areas where we as a community need to put in a bit more work.

So, if you are reading this, I am asking you to consider spending some time over the next week or so looking around yourself to see what needs to be done or improved. This is how I would love to see this work:

1. If it is something you can take care of, please do so.
2. If it is something that needs to be done but you can't do so, let us know here. Make sure to provide details and links when possible so someone who can get it done can do so more easily.
3. If it is something we should discuss as a community, please create a new meta question for it.
4. If you aren't sure, ask either here or we can create a chat room.

Here are just a few areas I could easily think of that can use some attention to make the site better:

- Our [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

  - Example questions were selected a while ago when we didn't have as much content. Are there better examples we should be using? Are there examples that should be removed?
  - Are there other ways to improve this page to make it clearer and easier to understand for new users?
- [Tags](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags)

  - Tag descriptions are missing on many tags. It would be nice if at least the two or three pages of the most popular tags all had descriptions.
  - Many existing tag descriptions could be improved.
  - Are there tags that need to be removed? Merged with other tags? Fixed to match the conventions we seem to have settled on?
  - Are there questions that are tagged incorrectly? Tags that should be removed or added to certain questions?
- Custom close reasons

  - In case you missed it, we recently [changed our default off-topic close reason](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/474/33) to hopefully improve the experience for users who have their questions put on hold.
  - Craig has [posted a discussion asking for suggestions for additional custom close reasons](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/509/33). If you have ideas or suggestions, please chime in.

I am sure there are many other places that could use a bit of improvement as well and I believe that if everyone chips it a little bit, we can make a significant improvement to the community as a whole.

Comment: This is a great idea @YLearn.  The Tags specifically have been bothering me for a while, but I haven't made time.  I'll find time this weekend to hammer on some Tag descriptions.

Answer (score 5):

Great initiative. I'll post one piece of feedback we as moderators received as a suggested improvement of this SE here:

At this moment, the "[what's on topic here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" page focuses on who the people posting are:

> "Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for Network Engineers."

One could argue that people may feel excluded here, and that it's better to focus on the type of content than on who people are. Looking at how the [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) StackExchange dinstinguishes itself from the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) SE, we may consider similar wording:

> "Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment."

can be transformed to something like

> "Network Engineering is for questions about managing networking equipment in a business environment."

How do people feel about this?

Comment: managing *networks* and networking equipment...

Comment: Yes, thanks for that suggestion.